# SVG Use -- Unable to repostion polygon after rotation

Tags: svg

I am trying to create a 16 point star inside a circle using SVG and pure CSS -- no JS!
My strategy is to create 16 equilateral triangles (via Defs and Use, to keep it DRY), rotating each Use iteration by 22.5 degrees.
My problem is that when I apply the rotate() transform to the second triangle, SVG changes the center point of the triangle -- which CSS3 does not (it rotates around a fixed axis).
I have tried adding x and y parameters, adding a class and doing a translate() transform, doing that inline... nothing works -- I just cant figure out how to move the triangle back into position (with a rotation) inside the circle (centered at 150, 150 I reckon).
Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the SVG line of code that I am having trouble with.

```
<use xlink:href="#triangle" style="transform: rotate(22.5deg);"  />
```

You can see it in action [here](https://codepen.io/zette/full/KJwWmv).

```css
<style > .toile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 800px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* centers outer containing element (the circle) horizontally & vertically */
  border: 5px #009000;
  /* green */
  border-style: groove;
  background-color: #f9e4b7;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* centers surface on a page */
}
```

```html
<div class="toile">
  <svg>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="grid" width="15" height="15" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="14" height="14"/>
    <rect fill="#009000" x="14" y="0" width="1" height="14"/>
    <rect fill="#009000" x="0" y="14" width="14" height="5"/>
   </pattern>

    <g id="triangle"> 
 <svg>
 <polygon points="150,18 200,100 100,100" 
 style="stroke:#009000;stroke-width:1; fill:#afeeee; opacity:.7" />
 </svg>
  </g>
  </defs>

  <rect fill="url(#grid)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <svg viewBox="0 100 400 400" stroke="#009000" stroke-width=".5" width="300" height="300" class="cercle">
   <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="75" fill="transparent" /> </svg>

  <svg viewBox="0 100 400 400" stroke="#ce2029" stroke-width=".5" width="300" height="300">
   <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="2" fill="#ce2029" /> </svg>

  <use xlink:href="#triangle" />
  <use xlink:href="#triangle" style="transform: rotate(22.5deg);" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Thank you for any solution to this problem; I just can't figure it out! Please no JS solutions!

UPDATE:

I've changed the 16-point gon to a 15 point one, as for some reason a series of 22.5 degree rotations create an unbalanced hexadecagon.  I got rid of the red circle center point, and the background grid, and added SVG animation.  [Here](https://codepen.io/zette/full/rPagQB) is the (final) working example.

Sorry about the CodePen but I am trying to figure out how to make snippets work for an entire HTML/CSS/SVG program.

Comment: Please remember to use the snippet functionality to move your code into the question to avoid link rot (I've done this for you)

Comment: You realise <use> elements have a huge perf overhead compared to just writing the shape(s) you want? Don't use the wrong tool just because it looks prettier.

Comment: I will try to find a way to calculate the exact performance hit of SVG <use> in order to assess your remark.  I am quite keen on DRY coding, in general, and repeating the polygons, one after the other, is IMHO somewhat grotesque.

Comment: Re the snippet functionality, I will try to figure out how to add code snippet to my answers. This is not immediately obvious, but I am learning! Meanwhile I do not plan on deleting example problem code in CodePen that I post here .

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it: 
First I simplified your code. Unless you have a good reason to do it like this, it's always better to keep things simple.

I calculated the points tor the triangle around the center of the svg canvas:
`<polygon id="triangle" points="200,125 264.95,237.5 135.05,237.5"`

I rotate the triangle using svg transforms: `transform="rotate(22.5,200,200)"`

The first value is the rotation in degs and next you have the x and y of the rotation center.

As it comes out with SVG transforms you don't have IE issues. Please read this article about [Transforms on SVG Elements](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/)

```css
.toile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 800px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* centers outer containing element (the circle) horizontally & vertically */
  border: 5px #009000;
  /* green */
  border-style: groove;
  background-color: #f9e4b7;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* centers surface on a page */
}
```

```html
<div class="toile">
   <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" stroke="#009000" stroke-width=".5" width="300" height="300" >
  <defs>
    <pattern id="grid" width="15" height="15" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="14" height="14"/>
    <rect fill="#009000" x="14" y="0" width="1" height="14"/>
    <rect fill="#009000" x="0" y="14" width="14" height="5"/>
   </pattern>

 
 <polygon id="triangle" points="200,125 264.95,237.5 135.05,237.5" 
 style="stroke:#009000;stroke-width:1; fill:#afeeee; opacity:.7" />

  </defs>

  <rect fill="url(#grid)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <circle class="cercle" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="75" fill="transparent" /> 
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="2" fill="#ce2029" /> 
   

  <use xlink:href="#triangle" />
  <use xlink:href="#triangle" transform="rotate(22.5,200,200)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

#### UPDATE

To calculate the points for the triangle you may use javascript. In the case of a regular polygon like a triangle all 3 vertices are on a circumscribed circle at a `2*Math.PI/3` angle one from each other. I'm starting with an offset of -Math.PI/2 (-90 degs) for the first vertex.

```js
// the center of the SVG canvas calculated from the values of the viewBox attribute. Alternatively you can choose a different point
 let c = {x:200,y:200}
 let radius = 75;
 let points = [];
 
 
 for(let a = -Math.PI/2; a < 3*Math.PI/2; a+= 2*Math.PI/3){
   let x = c.x + radius*Math.cos(a);
   let y = c.y + radius*Math.sin(a);
   points.push(x);
   points.push(y);
 }
 
 tri.setAttributeNS(null, "points", points.join());
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;height:90vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<polygon id="tri" />
</svg>
```

Comment: "I calculated the points tor the triangle around the center of the svg canvas:"  May I ask exactly how you did this?

Comment: I've updated my answer showing how to calculate the vertices of your triangle. If you don't want to use JS you can copy the values from the inspector.